# Set active link based on URL

Tags: jquery

If the URL ends: `?style=product` I want to add a class of `active` to the `li` with the class of `product`

HTML:

```
<ul id="menulist">
  <li class="product">Product</li>
  <li class="product2">Product 2</li>
  <li class="product3">Product 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're better off doing this server side when your HTML is output.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably go with Andy and render this serverside, but to answer your question, this is what you should do to achieve the same in javascript/jQuery (if, say, there is no server-side)

There are definitely easier ways of getting the 'style' querystring, if you can make a lot of assumptions about the url (that it will always have that querystring, that it will always be the *first* querystring, that there will never be any *other* querystrings, that there will never be any *hash* data after the querystring...). The below is probably the safest way to go if you *cannot* make such assumptions.

```
var activeStyle = '';

if(window.location.search != '') {
   // find querystring section or url
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);

   // split querystring into key/value-pairs
   query = query.split('&');

   for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {

       // split key/value pair into key and value
       var keyvalue = query[i].split('=');

       // find value of ?style=
       if(keyvalue[0].toLowerCase() == 'style')) {
          activeStyle = keyvalue[1];
          break;
       }
   }
}

if(activeStyle != '') {
   $('li.' + activeStyle).addClass('active');
}
```

Note that I assumed that you also want `product2` to become `active` in case your URL ends in `style=product2`. If you *only* want to apply this effect when `product` is selected, you would have to adjust the last condition to

```
if(activeStyle.toLowerCase() == 'product') {
    $('li.product').addClass('active');
}
```

**EDIT**

Edited the above selection to use `window.location.search` instead, to pick up on Andy's advice, which guards against `location.hash`.

Comment: Don't forget, you can use *window.location.search* to obtain only the query string part of the URL, then you don't have to worry about the hash :-)

Comment: @Andy: good catch! that's way better, as my original code didn't quite worry about hash enough. edited

Answer (score 1):

First up you'll need a javascript function similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery), this will allow you grab the style variable from the querystring.

Once you have that try something like:

```
var style = getParameterByName('style');
$('li.' + style).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getStyleValue(uri)
{
    var var, hash;
    var hashes = uri.slice(uri.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        if(hash[0] == 'style')
        {
            return hash[2];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

then you can use like

```
var selected = getStyleValue('index.php?style=product2') || "product";
$('a.' + selected).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the current url in jQuery like this:

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

Then cut off everything after '?' with a regex, to get yor current page

To add a class to the correct li-item:

```
$('li.'+style+').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var style = '<?php echo $_GET['style'] ?>';
if(style == 'product'){
    $('li.product').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use location.href to read the query parameters...

```
   function getQuerystring(key, default_)  {
      if (default_==null) default_="";
      key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
      var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
      if(qs == null)
        return default_;
      else
        return qs[1];
    }

    var target = $("." + getQueryString("style", "default"));
```